# What is the meaning of crossed Lag_plot?

Tags: correlation, arima, lags

I have a theoric-practical question.

Let's say I’ve got a seasonal series without trend.  I’ve tried to remove any covariances and fit an arima model. I’ve just tried several options and then I make a lag plot (lag_plot(residuals, lag= 1 ))  to know whether some correlation is present.
Well first try:
[image: lag Plot for lag 1]

Some outliers… but it is a cloud. So it seems no correlation... OK

And then I thought what about other lags? I tried for several values into a for loop and
[image]

It changes to an unshaped cloud after several lags. Have you ever seen a film with a spirit appearing and vanishing? For me is the same feeling. Does that mean that cross is formed by the points? Is it short of no linear correlation?

Original Data are hourly means so every lag is a different hour in the series. 24 lag is a day. Next ACF and Pacf below belong to residuals.
[image]

There may be any relationship between negative correlations at lag 24 with that star?
And another question do you think that these residuals are good? Or how can I remove the negative correlation? Adding a 24 to arima's q param?

Comment: I forgot to say it is done in Python pandas.plotting import lag_plot. pandas      0.25.1

Comment: Did you get any answer to your question?